# Fix path import when setting attribute inside imported module

Tags: python, module, setattr

To make it shorter, I have a module that does this:

```
MyModule
----mymodule.py
----__init__.py
```

**mymodule.py**

```
# Get the name of the current module
current_module = __import__(__name__)
setattr(current_module, 'VarA', 5)
```

So if Im in located inside the MyModule folder and open a shell, the following works:

```
import mymodule
print mymodule.VarA
```

But if Im localted outside MyModule folder and do:

```
from MyModule import mymodule
print mymodule.VarA
```

I get: `'module' object has no attribute 'VarA'`, which I suppose is happening because `setattr` is setting `VarA` somewhere else, what is it to be done so `VarA` is available in mymodule no matter where I import the module from ?

Comment: In `mymodule.py`, why do you use `setattr(..., 'VarA', 5)` instead of `VarA = 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

> When the name variable is of the form `package.module`, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, *not* the module named by *name*. However, when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by *name* is returned.

And you can see this very easily.

MyModule/mymodule.py:

```
current_module = __import__(__name__)
print current_module
```

Your program will print out something like this:

```
<module 'MyModule' from '/Users/abarnert/src/test/pkgtest3/MyModule/__init__.pyc'>
```

---

If you're using Python 2.7, you can skim over the rest of the documentation until this part:

> If you simply want to import a module (potentially within a package) by name, use [`importlib.import_module()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

So, just do that:

```
import importlib
current_module = importlib.import_module(__name__)
setattr(current_module, 'VarA', 5)
```

If you need to work with earlier 2.x versions, read the whole section (and for your Python version, not the 2.7 I linked above). The right answer is a bit more complicated, and a bit hacky:

```
import sys
current_package = importlib.import_module(__name__)
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(current_module, 'VarA', 5)
```

---

Of course if you're never going to run MyModule/mymodule.py as a top-level script, or `execfile` it or use custom import logic on it or anything like that, you don't need this complexity in the first place. Someone must have already `import`ed you, so just do this:

```
import sys
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(current_module, 'VarA', 5)
```

---

Of course the simplest solution here is:

VarA = 5

… but presumably there's a good reason that won't work in your real code.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I really posted an example of the problem I had, that is why I reduced it to setattr(...) I am adding dinamically generated classes to the module, but your answer is right. Thanks